# Angular 2: Number validation with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation

I'm trying to validate the number field in IE 11.

```
<input type="number" name="amount" [(ngModel)]="amount" (keypress)="validateNum($event) />
```

And in typescript

```
private validateNum(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const pattern = /^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,6}$/g;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if(!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to restrict the input to 3 digits and 5 decimals. The problem I'm facing is, regEx is validating for each key pressed (Not validating after the 3 digits pressed) and it is not allowing to enter any number. How do I validate the number after the numbers reach the restriction? Or is it possible to validate without regEx in Angular2?? I'm new to Angular and need suggestion.

Comment: why don't you simply test `this.amount` instead of inputChar? : `if(!pattern.test(this.amount))`

Comment: You should remove `g` modifier, too, you needn't the global modifier with `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `keypress` to `blur`. That way it will run the validation when the control loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

There's an awesome library called [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme). You can easily create a mask and restrict your user to input 3 digits and 5 decimals.

```
mask = [/\d/, /\d/,/\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
```