# Angular2: Number validation in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I'm trying to have a number validation in IE 11. I was referring [to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294054/angular-2-number-validation-with-regex/44297464#44297464). I'm unable to validate number with 2 digits and 3 decimals. Does typescript with IE 11 support Regular expressions? Or is there any other way to validate the number?

```
validateNum(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const pattern = /^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}$/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if(!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        event.preventDefault();;
    }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wCy3PHwIpvqYgtEwEqPP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/dQ8uWz3HRqpzGpacQAnZ?p=preview).

Note: The dot(.) in number pad doesn't register as keyboard event event in IE. But the dot in regular keyboard (between comma [,] and slash [/]) works fine.

Also, keypress doesn't register backspace, so I added a separate event handling for it.

Here's sample code:

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="amount" [(ngModel)]="amount" 
            (keypress)="validateNum($event, amount)" 
            (keydown.backspace)="handleBS()"/>`
```

App.ts:

```
data: string = "";

  validateNum(event: KeyboardEvent, amount): void {

    let pattern = new RegExp("^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}$");

    console.log(this.data);

    if(amount == undefined){
      pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1}$");
    }

    if(this.data.length >= 1 && this.data.length < 3){
       pattern = new RegExp("^[1-9]{1,3}$");
    }

    if(this.data.length == 3){
       pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}[.]$");
    }

    if(this.data.length > 3){
       pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}$");
    }

    if(this.data.length > 7){
       return false;
    }

    if(!pattern.test(this.data + event.key)) {
        return false;
    }
    this.data = this.data + event.key;
    return true;
  }

  handleBS(){
    this.data = this.data.slice(0, this.data.length - 1);
  }
```